# keep pixels 'sharp' after zoom with fabricjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am displaying images using fabricjs and enabled zooming using fabrics

```
myFabric.zoomToPoint({ x: x, y: y }, newZoom);
```

the problem is that when I zoom in the pixels are getting blurred instead of being kept 'sharp'\'separated' from one another.
zoomed out:

[image: zoomed out]
  zoomed in:
[image: zoomed in]

Comment: http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#imageSmoothingEnabled

Comment: don't know how I've missed that, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an [`imageSmoothingEnabled`](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#imageSmoothingEnabled) option you can pass at the creation of your fabric's Canvas :

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('a', {
  imageSmoothingEnabled: false // here you go
});
fabric.Image.fromURL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQRkt.png", function(img) {
  canvas.add(img);
  canvas.zoomToPoint({x: 50, y: 50}, 120);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="a" height="380" width="250"></canvas>
```